# The latest release of LaTeX2e changes behavior of \IfFileExists. Why?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, external-files

The output of the following latex document has changed since the last LaTeX2e release:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\IfFileExists
  {}
  { yes }
  { no }
\end{document}
```

Release 2020-02-02: **no**

Release 2020-10-01: **yes**

Why? Is this intended?

— *Update* —

Imagine we used a `test.tex.erb` file that is processed by Ruby first.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mypath}{<%= @image.path %>}
\IfFileExists
  {\mypath}
  {\includegraphics{\mypath}}
  { no image }
\end{document}
```

`@image.path` is sometimes `nil` making `\mypath` blank. This causes `\includegraphics{\mypath}` to fail since the latest LaTeX2e release (October 2020). In any previous LaTeX2e version the text “no image” would be rendered without error.

**Solution**

The easy solution that we use is this:

```tex
\newcommand{\mypath}{<%= @image.path || './inexistant.txt' %>}
```

Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, that was intended (see the [github issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/403)).  When you don't give an extension to a file, TeX assumes `.tex`, so `\IfFileExists{}` is the same as `\IfFileExists{.tex}`, and `.tex` _does_ exist in a LaTeX distribution.  I'm curious: what is your use-case for `\IfFileExists{}`?

Comment: Thanks, Phelype. We are dynamically generating the file from within a Ruby on Rails application using [rails-latex](https://github.com/amagical-net/rails-latex). Sometimes, an image path might be `nil`. In this case, the new LaTeX2e release breaks things, because `\includegraphics` then fails.

Comment: @Gregor without seeing any code it is hard to know what you mean but it sounds like you were not testing the right thing. `\includegraphics{}`  will try to load `.png` or `.pdf`   and would succeed if they exist.. `\IfFileExists{}` has _never_ checked for those files, it checks for `.tex` but due to a bug gave the wrong answer in older releases. But whether it returns true or false here it tells you nothing about whether `\includegraphics{}` would succeed.

Comment: @Gregor With `\includegraphics{}` I get ``LaTeX Error: File `' not found``.  If it was up to me, I'd filter the empty file in Ruby (I don't know Ruby nor your code, so that might be a crap suggestion), but if you _must_, you can do `\RequirePackage[2020/02/02]{latexrelease}` to restore the old (wrong) behaviour.  But that will undo all newer LaTeX changes (bug fixes included).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe the update to the question makes it more clear what we do.

Comment: after your edit the test seems wrong in all cases (if there is no extension in the path, not just empty) `\IfFileExists{/foo/bar/baz}{\includegraphics{/foo/bar/baz}}{no file}`  tests if `/foo/bar/baz.tex` exists, and if it does it tries to include `/foo/bar/baz.png`  why is that test useful?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your quick response. I have updated the question to give you a better idea of what we do. `.erb` files are embedded Ruby files that are processed by Ruby first.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The Ruby code `@image.path` would return `/foo/bar/baz.png` or `nil` – we don’t know.

Comment: @Gregor sure but I mean the tex code basically does not work (has never worked) if the file path has no extension, the fact that it almost seemed to work if it was completely empty was not by design. perhaps the ruby code never gives no extension so it doesn't affect you but from a purely tex question it's hard to give a really good answer as the code didn't work before anyway in general.

Comment: If you just want to get back to where you were use `\IfFileExists{\ifcat$\mypath$**missingfile**\else\mypath\fi}`  then an empty file will test as `**missing file**`  or you could presumably do the same in ruby use `@image.path==nil ? 'missing file' : @image.path`  (or whatever the ruby syntax is)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this case `@image.path==nil ? 'missing file' : @image.path` returns the same as `@image.path || 'missing file'` in Ruby. Problem solved, thank you.

Comment: @Gregor ah I nearly risked guessing the `||` idiom, but decided to go with `?` :-)